# Get number of unique children in an Array/dataSnapshot?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The code below allows me to get the number of children inside the `dataSnapshot`.

```
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                long numberChildren = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
```

My question is how do I get the number of **unique** children? Something like this would work perfectly: `dataSnapshot.getUniqueChildrenCount()`

Comment: you want for exemple get all sports for example

Comment: what do your children look like? I think you have to count all occurences and return the number of those with only one occurence…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach without using set:

```
ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String children = childDataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if (!values.contains(children)) {
                    values.add(newValue);
                }

            }
```

approach using set:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String children = childDataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                set.add(children);

            }
```

Comment: This answer works well but `Set` seems to be the most efficient solution here. Upvoted.

Comment: The other person deleted his answer. Please consider adding a `Set` solution also to your answer :)

Comment: The declaration of the `ArrayList` and the `Set` in both cases, should be inside the `onDataChange()` method otherwise the collections are null. For having the answer 100% correct, you need to move those declarations inside that method.